# C# trap click on URL (hyper link) with reading pane of Outlook message

Tags: c#, url, outlook, system-calls

I am trying to figure out how to trap when a user clicks on a URL within a message that is open in Outlook, then pass the URL to a function, perform a test on that string, and if it is valid, let it go.

I already have an Outlook Add-In and I realize there is no native way to do this. But I am looking for that one expert out there to help me figure out what I am trying to do.

My initial thought at trying to tackle this was to maybe trap the Windows system call that is being performed, and I should be able to parse that message, get the string, perform the function, and then decide to let it go on or not - or some other way.

I would like to see a working C# functions that minimally parses the string.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. I don't think you can intercept such things. Instead, consider using the following workarounds:

- A proxy is a good choice if you just need the URL string to be processed. But anything more complex will be complicated to implement in a proxy.
- A plugin however, depends on which browser you are targetting, you can't make a single plugin that targets all browser and control user navigation at the same time. But if you get to selects which browser your user uses, then maybe.